# Single Sign On - Office 365 Using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, single-sign-on

We have a web application in which login/signup is already there. Now we want to allow Office 365 users to login into our application even if they dont have account in our application. I have google it more to find it. But i want PHP Api to integrate it.

**Is there any PHP api for this?**

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: A little googling would have helped.. Anyways, refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25288562/1681154

Comment: where it shows PHP Api?

Comment: Pardon for the dead link in comment above, I think this might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28727602/1681154

Comment: Also, this thread covers the scenarios http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509761/connect-to-azure-active-directory-from-php-web-application